# Operations between sets of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, syntax, sets

sorry it was impossible to put the code in Latex, he said that there were problems of indentation, I put the image

[image]

Comment: Is this anything to do with Mathematica (the programming language)? If so, one should consult the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I follow your notation:

```
u = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
a = {1, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4};
b = {6, 10, 11, 9, 3, 1};
c = {5, 9, 11, 10, 2, 4};

CircleMinus = Complement;
pr[x_] := u⊖x;


a⊖(b ⋂ c)

(pr[a] ⋃ pr[b]) ⋂ a

((b ⋃ c) ⋂ a)⊖(a ⋂ b ⋂ c)

((b⊖a) ⋂ (c⊖a)) ⋂ pr[b ⋃ c]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8}
>
> {2, 4, 7, 8}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
>
> {}
> ```

Comment: Thank , Thank you very much, I could explain a little how the code works and who is PR [x]

Comment: @Walter `CircleMinus = Complement` sets `⊖` as a shorthand for `Complement`.  `pr` is a function I defined with my best guess as to the meaning of your prime in `a'`, `b'` etc.; sorry if I got it wrong. `⋃` and  `⋂` are built-in notation for `Union` and `Intersection`.

Comment: Thank , Thank you very much